# django unit testing timezone

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

In my settings.py I have implemented timezone as

```
TIME_ZONE = os.environ.get("TIMEZONE", "Europe/London")
```

I've tried something like

```
    assert timezone.localtime() == timezone.get_current_timezone()

    print(timezone.localtime())
    print(timezone.get_current_timezone())
```

How would I change get_current_timezone so that it could be compared to localtime

Comment: Seems like you want to write tests for `os.environ.get(...)` method, which is already tested

Comment: I want to write test to see if the timezone is correctly being used as europe/london

Comment: @JPG added some desciptions

Comment: Maybe `freezetime` package is what you need?